# Docx4j replace a text by picture in XML

Tags: java, xml, docx4j

I want replace a text by a picture in the XML structure of a docx file.
I've tried something like that:
First I search the good text in the XML and after I create a drawing object to put the picture in.

```
List<Object> list = this.getDocumentPart().getJAXBNodesViaXPath(xpath, false);
org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory  factory  =  Context.getWmlObjectFactory();
org.docx4j.wml.P para = factory.createP();
org.docx4j.wml.Drawing draw = factory.createDrawing();
((R)list.get(0)).getContent().clear();
((R)list.get(0)).getContent().add(draw);
para.getContent().add(((R)list.get(0)));
try {
    this.getWordMLPackage().save(new java.io.File("C:\\user\\result.docx") );
} catch (Docx4JException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now I don't know what put in the draw to add my picture, and at this step when I want to open my docx there is a problem. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix the problem so I post the solution, maybe it will help someone.

First you need to know that we are going to add a Inline in the Drawing so we need 2 funtion.
The first to convert the picture in a ByteArray;

```
private static byte[] convertImageToByteArray(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file );
    long length = file.length();
    if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        System.out.println("Fichier trop volumineux.");
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];
    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (offset < bytes.length  && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
        offset += numRead;
    }
    if (offset < bytes.length) {
        System.out.println("Impossible de lire en entier le fichier: " + file.getName());
    }
    is.close();
    return bytes;
}
```

After that you need to create the Inline:

```
public Inline createInline(File filePict) throws Exception{
    byte[] bytes = convertImageToByteArray(filePict);
    BinaryPartAbstractImage imagePart = BinaryPartAbstractImage.createImagePart(this.getWordMLPackage(), bytes);
    int id1 = 1;
    int id2 = 2;
    Inline inline = imagePart.createImageInline("Filename hint", filePict.getName(), id1, id2, false);
    return inline;
}
```

And at the add the Inline to the Drawing:

```
File fileLogo = new File(this.cusDir+mappings.get("logo"));
org.docx4j.wml.Drawing draw = factory.createDrawing();
((R)list.get(i)).getContent().clear();
((R)list.get(i)).getContent().add(draw);
draw.getAnchorOrInline().add(createInline(fileLogo));
```